# Read and write BMP image (grayscale)

Tags: c, image, bmp

I have this code to read bmp image and then write it in new image. The problem that I faced is that the resulting image from `write_bmp` function give the same size of the original reading image but I can not open the image because it corrupted.
Can you help me to solve the issue in the code please?
thank you in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct {
    uint16_t signature;
    uint32_t file_size;
    uint32_t reserved;
    uint32_t data_offset;
    uint32_t header_size;
    int32_t width;
    int32_t height;
    uint16_t planes;
    uint16_t bits_per_pixel;
    uint32_t compression;
    uint32_t image_size;
    int32_t x_pixels_per_meter;
    int32_t y_pixels_per_meter;
    uint32_t total_colors;
    uint32_t important_colors;
} BMPHeader;
#pragma pack(pop)


void read_bmp(const char* filename, uint8_t** image_data, int32_t* width, int32_t* height, uint16_t* bits_per_pixel)
{
    FILE* file = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (!file) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open the file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    BMPHeader header;
    fread(&header, sizeof(BMPHeader), 1, file);

    if (header.signature != 0x4D42) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid BMP file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    *width = header.width;
    *height = header.height;
    *bits_per_pixel = header.bits_per_pixel;

    int32_t row_padding = (4 - ((*width) % 4)) % 4;
    int32_t row_size = (*width) + row_padding;
    int32_t data_size = row_size * abs(*height);

    *image_data = (uint8_t*)malloc(data_size);
    if (!*image_data) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fseek(file, header.data_offset, SEEK_SET);

    int32_t row;
    for (row = 0; row < abs(*height); ++row) {
        fread(*image_data + (row * row_size), 1, *width, file);
        fseek(file, row_padding, SEEK_CUR);
    }

    fclose(file);
}

void write_bmp(const char* filename, const uint8_t* image_data, int32_t width, int32_t height, uint16_t bits_per_pixel)
{
    FILE* file = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if (!file) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open the file 4 write\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    int32_t row_padding = (4 - ((width * (bits_per_pixel / 8)) % 4)) % 4;
    int32_t row_size = (width * (bits_per_pixel / 8)) + row_padding;
    int32_t data_size = row_size * abs(height);

    BMPHeader header;
    header.signature = 0x4D42;
    header.file_size = sizeof(BMPHeader) + data_size;
    header.reserved = 0;
    header.data_offset = sizeof(BMPHeader);
    header.header_size = sizeof(BMPHeader) - 14;
    header.width = width;
    header.height = height;
    header.planes = 1;
    header.bits_per_pixel = bits_per_pixel;
    header.compression = 0;
    header.image_size = data_size;
    header.x_pixels_per_meter = 0;
    header.y_pixels_per_meter = 0;
    header.total_colors = 0;
    header.important_colors = 0;

    fwrite(&header, sizeof(BMPHeader), 1, file);

    int32_t row;
    for (row = 0; row < abs(height); ++row) {
        fwrite(image_data + (row * width * (bits_per_pixel / 8)), 1, (width * (bits_per_pixel / 8)), file);
        uint8_t padding[3] = {0};
        fwrite(padding, 1, row_padding, file);
    }

    fclose(file);
}

int main()
{

    const char* input_filename = "C:/Users/pp/Desktop/r/lena.BMP";
    const char* output_filename = "C:/Users/pp/Desktop/r/ccoutput.BMP";


    uint8_t* image_data;
    int32_t width, height;
    uint16_t bits_per_pixel;

    read_bmp(input_filename, &image_data, &width, &height, &bits_per_pixel);
    printf("bits_per_pixel = %d \n",bits_per_pixel );

    // Access and process the image data as needed

    write_bmp(output_filename, image_data, width, height, bits_per_pixel);

    free(image_data);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably something wrong with the data in BMPHeader. In write_bmp, you seem to hard-code the values in the header, this may be wrong, I would suggest to copy (parts of) the header from the one obtained in read_bmp. If everything fails, perform a binary comparison of the original vs the output image and see where they differ.

Comment: Try reading the entire bitmap file with a single `fread` and then `fwrite` it. Does that work? If so, proceed to altering the colouring. The bit depth will be relevant: 24 and 32-bit images have the colours encoded directly into the pixel, and 8-bit colour uses a palette look-up table (who uses 16 bits today?). So you either edit the pixel rgb values or the palette rgb values.

Comment: Any reason not to use a properly tested, tried and true library?

Comment: @clodia, Why are the return values of `fread(&header, sizeof(BMPHeader), 1, file);` and `fread(*image_data + (row * row_size), 1, *width, file);` not checked?

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at your code, it looks like you forgot about the color palette data that comes between the end of the header and the beginning of the pixel data. For this answer, I am using [this](https://eeweb.engineering.nyu.edu/%7Eyao/EL5123/image/lena_gray.bmp) image as a test.

The difference in the size of the input file and output file is exactly 1026 bytes. Since the image has 8 bits per pixel and colors are stored in the 4-byte RGBA32 format, the table takes up 2^8*4=1024 bytes. Note that the color table is not optional for images with bits-per-pixel <= 8.

The remaining two bytes that account for the 1026-byte image size difference appear to be a 2-byte null terminator at the end of the file.

Additionally, in your `read_bmp` function, you don't take into account the bits-per-pixel in the way that you do in `write_bmp`.

Finally, you should heed Sven Nilsson's advice because your calculations for the header is also not totally correct.

Sources:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Color_table